# Flask - How to get the file extenstion, without using file.content_type

Tags: python, flask

I have this code:

```py
@app.route("/mobile/upload", methods=["POST"])
async def upload_file():
    uploaded_files = await request.files
    uploaded_file = uploaded_files['file']
    uploaded_file_name = generate_name()
    
    fmt = content_type.get(uploaded_file.content_type)
    
    if fmt not in content_type:
        
        return f"That file type is not supported yet ({uploaded_file.filename}{uploaded_file.content_type}), adding now!"
    
    full_name = uploaded_file_name + fmt
    
    await uploaded_file.save("./static/" + full_name)
    return redirect("/static/" + full_name)
```

And what I would like to do is get the file extenstion, like .md, .txt and automatically add it to the list of allowed content types.

I have looked at the docs but can't find what I'm looking for.

Heres the content type list:

```
content_type = {
    "image/png": ".png",
    "image/gif": ".gif",
    "image/jpeg": ".jpeg",
    "text/plain": ".txt",
    "text/html": ".html",
    "audio/mpeg": ".mp3",
    "video/mp4": ".mp4",
    "text/x-generic": ".py",
    "application/x-msdownload": ".exe"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you add the extension to your allow list, why check the extension in the first place?

Comment: What about the extenstions i cant think off? This is use for all people so when Im not at my pc this would be helpful

Comment: **Security alert**: do not rely on the MIME type because it is set by the browser and can be spoofed. Check the file extension instead. Check [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/) for examples.

Comment: OK, Thats fine, I do need to find a way to add the different file extension to the llist.

Comment: I still do not get why you need a list, if you allow any new extension.

Comment: I see what you mean now, im sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comments, it seems your answer is pretty clear.

Just allow any file type and don't use MIME types.

Thank @Anonymous and @J.G.